# Android WebView EvaluateJavasctipt using Xamarim, evaluating wrong page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I am trying to load data from an element on a webpage but it seems to be getting the data from the incorrect page.

I call webview.loadUrl("url1")

then from there i override a popup using ShouldOverrideLoading and call webview.loadUrl("url2") inside the same webview and on OnPageFinished I override this as well and call evaluatejavascript("document.getElementById(id)") on that webview inside of OnPageFinished.

I would expect to get data from the second url on the result, but it is pulling data from the first url that was loaded. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Thank you in advance!

```
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        return HandleUrlLoading(view,url);
    }

     public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        string url = request.Url.ToString();
        return HandleUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    private bool HandleUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        _handleUrlOverride?.Invoke(view, url);
        return true; // then it is not handled by default action
    }

    public void UrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        switch (State)
        {
            case State.PlayerlessLobby:
                _loginView.LoadUrl(url);
                _progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                _lobbyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                _state = State.Login;
                break;
            case State.Lobby:
                _gameView.LoadUrl(url);
                _progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                _loginView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                _lobbyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                _state = State.Game;
                break;
            case State.Game:
                break;
            case State.Login:
                _loginView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                _progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                _loginView.LoadUrl(url);
                _state = State.Lobby;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The UrlLoading method is assigned to _handleUrlOverride

What happening is _loginView loads the login page

```
    _loginView.LoadUrl(url);
    _progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    _lobbyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    _state = State.Login;
```

Then on the login page i enter credentials and hit login. The login page redirects and goes into this code.

```
     _loginView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
     _progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
     _loginView.LoadUrl(url);
     _state = State.Lobby;
```

The OnPageFinished after loginView loads the redirect is this

```
    var result = new JavaScriptResult();
    result.SetCallback(this);
    _loginView.EvaluateJavascript("document.body.children[0].innerHTML", result);
    _loginView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

But the javascript that returns is a div from the first page.

Edit:

It seems that even though I override the popup load, and if I dont call webview.loadUrl("url2") the onPageFinished still gets triggered for this page. So I don't get why it would be loading even though it should be overriden.

Comment: Can you please show some code of your `ShouldOverrideLoading`?

Comment: I updated it with the requested code

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're trying to authenticate user account when your webview navigate to a Url, are you sure there is such method for this website to authenticate in this way with provided user account and password? I think you possibly went to a wrong direction.

From the customer site for this website, it's possible that users can login with their accounts and password, but when we develop such an app, we need to follow the website's Login developer methods, for example, you can google "facebook login developer", it will show you [Add Facebook Login to Your App or Website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login). There is [official way for android app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android), or you can try to use the [Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens) for login, also take the facebook for example, you can refer to [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/).

And if there are rest apis for your website, you can try using [WebClient](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebClient/) to send http request and receive response from your website.

Comment: The login works fine through a normal browser and the redirect page loads. No issues with logging in.

So what happens on the server side is it logs the player in creates a token and passes me back a url to load with the generated token. This is all working and tested. The issue I am seeing is on the override for the redirect the webview never loads the page but according the the pagefinished method it does, but the pages content is not there its still the old page.

I was not able to fix this specific issue but we did change the way our login flow works to get around this not working.

Comment: @DerekLawrence, I can only tell that webview is not a normal browser, you can read the official doc of `WebView` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: @DerekLawrence: Official doc says: By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine; the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it, and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a WebView.